# ActiveRecord: Alternative to find_in_batches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query that loads thousands of objects and I want to tame it by using `find_in_batches`:

`Car.includes(:member).where(:engine => "123").find_in_batches(batch_size: 500) ...`

According to the docs, I can't have a custom sorting order: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActiveRecord/Batches:find_in_batches

However, I need a custom sort order of `created_at DESC`. Is there another method to run this query in chunks like it does in find_in_batches so that not so many objects live on the heap at once?

Comment: Great question.  Did you look at [this gem](https://github.com/dburry/each_batched)?  Only about 5,000 downloads so it may take some work.  If you don't get a better answer and wind up trying this it would be interesting to hear how it worked.

Comment: Are you trying to do a custom sort order on the original query (so you pull 500 at a time in a specific order) or sorting on the results you getting back (sort the 500 only)?

Comment: Sorting the original query, not just the batch

Comment: If you want to sort the original query I believe adding .order("created_at DESC") after the where would sort the original query.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. It also prints a warning `Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size`

Comment: This sounds like you are asking about **pagination**, ie loading one page's worth of resources at a time.  *will_paginate* is a popular solution https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: @MaxWilliams yeh i was just thinking that. I think i'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm I've been thinking about a solution for this (I'm the person who asked the question). It makes sense that `find_in_batches` doesn't allow you to have a custom order because lets say you sort by `created_at DESC` and specify a batch_size of 500. The first loop goes from 1-500, the second loop goes from 501-1000, etc. What if before the 2nd loop occurs, someone inserts a new record into the table? That would be put onto the top of the query results and your results would be shifted 1 to the left and your 2nd loop would have a repeat.

You could argue though that `created_at ASC` would be safe then, but it's not guaranteed if your app specifies a created_at value.

UPDATE:

I wrote a gem for this problem: https://github.com/EdmundMai/batched_query

Since using it, the average memory of my application has HALVED. I highly suggest anyone having similar issues to check it out! And contribute if you want!

Answer (score 1):

The slower manual way to do this, is to do something like this:

```
count = Cars.includes(:member).where(:engine => "123").count
count = count/500
count += 1 if count%500 > 0
last_id = 0
while count > 0
    ids = Car.includes(:member).where("engine = "123" and id > ?", last_id).order(created_at: :desc).limit(500).ids #which plucks just the ids`   
    cars = Cars.find(ids)
    #cars.each or #cars.update_all
    #do your updating 
    last_id = ids.last
    count -= 1
end
```

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, if you're looking for pagination, there is a gem for that. If you are looking for a way to iterate over the large data set for updating or pulling queries something like this works as long as you keep track of the last `id` you pulled. It just has to make multiple calls to do so, but the second call is pulling based on the id index at least.

Answer (score 0):

Can you imagine how `find_in_batches` with sorting will works on 1M rows or more? It will sort all rows every batch.

So, I think will be better to decrease number of sort calls. For example for batch size equal to 500 you can load IDs only (include sorting) for N * 500 rows and after it just load batch of objects by these IDs. So, such way should decrease have queries with sorting to DB in N times.

Comment: It defaults to sorting on `id ASC`. how is that any different?

Comment: You can define an index on a database column, so that the database does not sort it for each request.