# Use group by with find_in_batches in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a topic_followers table in MySQL with schema like this

```
id, user_id, topic_id, creation_date, modified_date
```

I tried to use expression below to get list of topics each user is following:

```
TopicFollower.select("user_id, group_concat(topic_id) as topic_ids").group("user_id").find_in_batches { |group| ... }
```

However, find_in_batches automatically adds "ORDER BY `topic_followers`.`id` ASC" to the query and forces me to add "id" to select clause which conflicts agains group clause. Any suggestion how I can do batch requests with group?

Another related question, is there a rule of thumb on when I should start batching the requests? What's the decision process like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord: Alternative to find\_in\_batches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510180/activerecord-alternative-to-find-in-batches)

Answer (score 0):

```
TopicFollower.find_in_batches(batch_size: 300) do |objects|
 objects.group_by { |object| object&.user_id}
end
```

Comment: Hi Narendran V, welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I.e., code-only answers are not that good.